# Why didn't Jason kill his last victim?

Tags: plot-explanation, friday-the-13th, friday-the-13th-1980

In [Friday The 13th](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Friday_the_13th_(1980_film)), Jason pulled his last victim into the lake.

[image]

But *why* did Jason spare his last victim's life?

Comment: Wasn't that part just supposed to be a dream?

Comment: I must point out here that Jason doesn't kill _anybody_ in _Friday the 13th_--his mother, Pamela, is the killer.  And yeah, that's a dream sequence there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This was mentioned in the comments, but needs to be an answer.

The scene described was just a dream sequence, and had no real bearing on the 'facts' of the movie, which were that Jason wasn't actually even alive in this movie, and that the killings ended with the death of his mother.

Until Part II that is!

Comment: No need to turn this into Community Wiki. It's your answer and there's no need for it to be easily collaboratively constructed, which is the only thing CW is used for.

Answer (score 0):

The movie is about the perils of the transition into adulthood, with its greater  responsibilities.  It doesn't seem like the Voorhees are necessarily motivated by taking more victims: even Mrs. Voorhees stays within the camp.  Given these facts and themes, I'd say Jason lets Alice live so she can tell the tale, and warn other people about the camp and the importance of responsibility.

Comment: Agree with user22792, it's a dream sequence. Jason was supposed to be dead, they didn't bring him back unti they saw the box office receipts.

Comment: Sequels had become common (Exorcist, Omen, Jaws), and the scene blatantly allows for a sequel: "he's still out there."  Even if it's interpreted as only a dream, it's still reasonable to ask for an explanation that fits the franchise as a whole.  Within the continuity, if just a dream it's a prophetic dream by someone who's lost touch with reality -- she's certain Jason was there, at the camp.

Comment: Actually, this movie was ripping off the final scene in "Carrie"(1976), but that was also a dream sequence and Carrie was still dead. I still think it was done just to shock and not to promote a sequel.